# AMPScript convert "feb" to 02

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, date, cloudpage, format

I'm looking to convert a data field value (@OPT2) from "01-Feb-22" into "01-02-22" to be displayed on a landing page.
The reason is I want to display the date in French too and having Feb in the is not allowing me to display the date in French. Here is the code i'm using so far

````
        VAR @OPT2, @FormattedDate
        SET @OPT2 = QueryParameter("OPT2")
        SET @FormattedDate = Format(@OPT2, "d MMMM yyyy", "Date", "fr-CA")
       ]%%-->```
It will be output using:
```%%=V(@FormattedDate)=%%```

Thank you
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FormatDate` function in AMPscript to do that. Try this:

```
%%[
VAR @OPT2, @FormattedDate
        SET @OPT2 = QueryParameter("OPT2")
        SET @FormattedDate = FormatDate(@OPT2, 'dd-MM-yy')
]%%
%%=v(@FormattedDate)=%%
```

Comment: Thank you it is working :)